# How can I check the wordpress theme on my system?

Tags: wordpress, web-applications, wordpress-theming

I have doubt in using the wordpress theme. I had downloaded a wordpress theme for my website from wordpress.org. I need to know how do i test it. The theme name is "pagelines". When i run it on my server it shows me webpage not found. How will i be able to test it out.

Please help....

Comment: Go to Appearance->Themes, select the upper tab "Install Themes" and search and install the themes you want. Then you can preview them and eventually activate them.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to unzip the theme file you have downloaded and place in your themes folder then go to admin panel

```
admin ->appearance -> Themes
```

there the themes will be displayed

you can view the new theme here and activate the theme

now your theme will be enabled on your wordpress, you can check your home page

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the Wordpress' Using Themes guide? Read this guide first http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes. It will clarify a lot of your questions.